# Finding an enclosed area using integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area enclosed by $y=\frac 8{x^2}$, $y=x$, $x=8$

The answer says the area is equal to $27$. I tried dividing the area into $2$ (one of them a right angled triangle). I found the area of the triangle to be $2$. But when I calculate the total area, including the other shape, I can't seem to get the right answer.

Any guidance/help is appreciated

Comment: If you cut the region horizontally with the line y=2, then the top portion is a triangle with A=18 and the bottom portion has A=9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\text{Area} & = \int_2^8 \left(x- \frac{8}{x^2}\right) dx \\
&=\left(\frac12x^2+\frac{8}{x}\right) |_2^8 \\
&=\left(\left(\frac{8^2}{2}+\frac{8}{8}\right)-\left(\frac{2^2}{2}+\frac{8}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=27
\end{align}$$

Comment: where did the x in the first line come from?

Comment: The area is bounded above by $y=x$ and below by $\frac{8}{x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Take these steps for clarification

1. Draw the curves.
2. Notice where they intersect(or better yet, calculate it). These will be your boundaries.
3. Find which curve is above and which is below.
4. Integrate the above curve - below curve (y=x - y=8/x**2 in this case, as the given answer shows better).